# Drupal 7 - delete own account

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I just installed drupal-7.16. I would like to have following functionality:
As a non-admin user I would like to delete/block my own account.

Is it possible?
I found User Delete module, but there is no version for drupal 7.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found that it's possible from drupal properties.

Just log in as admin, go to People -> Permission
and enable permission "Cancel own user account" for authenticated users.